# Download old version of Mac OSX legally as Apple Developer?

Tags: macos, development

I have an Apple Developer license, and an old MacBook that I want to use only as a build server for developing Phonegap applications.

The Mac is too old to get anything newer than 10.9, but in order to use correct IOS SDK, it needs 10.9 or newer.

I was able to find and upgrade from 10.4 to 10.6 with no problem, but I can't seem to find Mavericks as a complete install or update file.  Unless I am missing something.  I looked in the developer downloads, but all those downloads seem to be upgrades only for people who already own 10.9.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

I never owned any version of OSX that I can go back and get the installer for as this computer was a gift that had never been updated beyond 10.4. My intention is 'pure'.  Seems like I should be able to do this somehow.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, I have discovered that this is not possible.  According to Apple, Mavericks has been phased out and can no longer even be purchased.

This seems stupid and pointless; but it probably allows them to avoid the pain of writing certain kinds of updates; dealing with backwards compatibility, etc.

I'm sure Mavericks can be had on eBay or somewhere else.  That said, this was not the outcome I was hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

Log into your account and navigate to the summary account overview page:

- https://developer.apple.com/account/#/overview/

  1. Select Downloads
  2. Scroll the page so you can see additional downloads at the bottom
  3. Uncheck all but OS X category
  4. Search for 10.9 and grab the combo you want.

At that point, open a case with developer support and ask them to send you a redemption code for 10.9 for your Mac App Store account.

Comment: So I select any of the one's that say "Combo Update"  and then ask for developer support?

Comment: Yup @user1167442  - You don't necessarily need to get the combo first, but it validates you are active and you've already looked for the file. Perhaps they have it hidden and will take the hint to let us get these ourselves and it shows you tried hard to find it first.

Comment: Gotcha - thanks.  I'll comment and mark this the correct answer if it works.

Comment: @user1167442 Please edit my post to make it just how you like :-)