# Upgrade to old version of MacOS X

Tags: macos, upgrade

I have an old MacBook Pro (mid-2010) and I am currently running Mountain Lion. Due to lack of any type of support (I cannot install most new versions of applications), I think about installing a newer version, but I don't want the most recent as it will slow my computer down too much. Ideally I would like to upgrade to Mavericks.

I saw a similar topic, which unfortunately doesn't answer my question (as I have never installed my desired version with my Apple ID):

[How can I download an older version of OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x)

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/258219/88313).  It looks like you can't even download Mavericks anymore as Apple has removed it.

Comment: I'm not sure how the linked question doesn't answer this. It states that if you don't have it in your purchase history you will need a friend or a torrent.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I'd just get it from torrents since you basically own a copy anyways. Easy.